# Merge data when change coredata version

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

Before looking at the problems, let's take a look at my coredata schema:

The version 1 of my coredata's schema:

```
--Entity:
<Family>, <Member>, <Note>

<Note> Attribute:
content: string

--Relationship:
Family 1-many Member
Member 1-1 Note (*)
```

In version 2, the coredata schema:

```
--Entity:
<Family>, <Member>, <Note>

<Note> Attribute:
content: string

--Relationship:
Family 1-1 Note (*)
Family 1-many Member
```

So, it means that I want upgrade scope of note from member to family (look at those * in both versions).

The question is: How do I merge the content of all the notes of all member to one big note, then add to the new family's note.

Example:

```
Before:
family.mem1.note = "mem1 note"
family.mem2.note = "mem2 note"

After:
family.note = "mem1 note, mem2 note"
```

P/S: I'm sorry to ask this kind of question, since all I know about migrate coredata is lightweight migrate. At this problem, lightweight migrate delete all the note, which is the option I don't want. Apple doesn't have much documents about migrate like... this.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this programatically.  I would suggest keep your existing Member-Note in the new model and add the Family-Note.  Now lightweight migration will work, and then once migration has completed use a custom function to update each Family.note by iterating over all Family.members and appending the member.note to the Family.note.

Comment: Probably not a good way to make an app... Programatically, I agree with this part. But to seprate it in 2 steps and using lightweight migrate, obviously not a good way to make it work. I want to use the other way, like custom migrate or something like that... Sorry, your solution doesn't fit well here.